# Python comments not highlighted with lstlisting

Tags: lstlisting

I want to use `lstlisting` for some Python code, and I have a code segment that looks like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstloadlanguages{Python}
\lstset{
  language=Python,
  basicstyle=\scriptsize\sffamily,
  numberstyle=\color{gray},
  stringstyle=\color[HTML]{933797}
  commentstyle=\color[HTML]{228B22}\sfffamily,
  emph={[2]from,import,pass,return}, emphstyle={[2]\color[HTML]{DD52F0}},
  emph={[3]range}, emphstyle={[3]\color[HTML]{D17032}},
  emph={[4]for,in,def}, emphstyle={[4]\color{blue}},
  showstringspaces=false,
  breaklines=true,
  prebreak=\mbox{{\color{gray}\tiny$\searrow$}},
  numbers=left,
  xleftmargin=15pt
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
# Function definitions

# Test cases
for _ in range(100):
    # Test comment
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

But the comments that start with `#` are not highlight with my specified color, they are just black. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three issues here: (1) `gray` is not defined by default in `color`, generally use `xcolor` instead. (2) there is a comma missing after `stringstyle=\color[HTML]{933797}`. (3) one too many f's in `\sfffamily`

Then the example works for me

Updated MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstloadlanguages{Python}
\lstset{
  language=Python,
  basicstyle=\scriptsize\sffamily,
  numberstyle=\color{gray},
  stringstyle=\color[HTML]{933797},
  commentstyle=\color[HTML]{228B22}\sffamily,
  emph={[2]from,import,pass,return}, emphstyle={[2]\color[HTML]{DD52F0}},
  emph={[3]range}, emphstyle={[3]\color[HTML]{D17032}},
  emph={[4]for,in,def}, emphstyle={[4]\color{blue}},
  showstringspaces=false,
  breaklines=true,
  prebreak=\mbox{{\color{gray}\tiny$\searrow$}},
  numbers=left,
  xleftmargin=15pt
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
# Function definitions

# Test cases
for _ in range(100):
    # Test comment
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly,

```
\lstdefinelanguage{Python}{
commentstyle=\color{white}\sffamily
}
```

would not work but

```
\lstset{
  language=Python,
commentstyle=\color{white}\sffamily
}
```

would, it is something to check out.